# do LCD TVs also use phosphor coated screen?

Tags: lcd

do LCD TVs also use phosphor coated screen? if not, then what is the cause of their after-glow in the dark for few seconds? since we know that glow in the dark stuffs glow generally because of phosphors but i want to know if LCD TVs do not contain phosphor coated screens to form images then why do they glow in dark for few seconds after being turned off?

Answer (score 1):

LCD TVs use a fluorescent backlight which contains phosphors which, when excited, will emit a net white light. That light is transmitted through the LCD where the image is formed and its intensity and color controlled by electrical signals driving tiny pixels located behind tiny RGB color filters.

The afterglow you've noticed is due to the fairly slow decay in the output of the backlight when it's shut down.

Comment: Assuming it has a CFL backlight, and not a LED backlight?

Comment: @Passerby even in white LED there is a phosphor which converts the blue light to all the other wavelengths. Though the afterglow should be barely noticeable.

Comment: i too tried to observe the after-glow in LED TVs but i  didn't see any...